# VB - simply link a Data Grid View to display data that was selected from a ComboBox

Tags: vb.net

I just want to display data in a DataGridView (from SQL - already made the connection) based on what is selected in a ComboBox (data that is also coming from SQL). The 2 are separete on the form. I am using VB 2010.

This doesn't work for me:
objCommand2.CommandText = "SELECT ProductID, Name, Color, Size, ListPrice FROM SalesLT.Product WHERE ProductCategoryID = " & cbCategory.SelectedValue

It gives me an error "invalid syntax around '=' "

Thank you!!!
Catalin

Comment: Are you sure about the SalesLT.Product Name? Maybe just using `FROM Product`?

Comment: SalesLT.Product is correct. But the SQL statement ends at " WHERE =": objCommand2.CommandText = "SELECT ProductID, Name, Color, Size, ListPrice FROM SalesLT.Product WHERE ProductCategoryID = "

Comment: I think the concatenation "&" doesn't work correctly in this case ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
cbCategory.SelectedText
```

and look into passing command parameters to a stored procedure in the future.

Comment: "... WHERE ProductCategoryID = " & cbCategory.SelectedTest doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to assign the long string to a variable first to see if it really looks like a SQL statement. As Saif suggested, it may be something related to the value of the combobox. What I usually do is hardcode a SQL statement in a string to make the function work and then replace it with the dynamic string.

```
Dim s As String = "SELECT ProductID FROM SalesLT.Product WHERE ProductCategoryID=1"
```

One simple step at a time

Answer (score 0):

Check that cbCategory.SelectedValue is indeed a numeric value. If it is, say "XXY", then you would need to code

```
WHERE ProductCategoryID = '" & cbCategory.SelectedValue & "'"
```

(watch out for the difference between ' and " !